# Packaging a project that uses multiple python versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pipenv

I'm trying to package a project that is mainly based on python 3 but uses some python 2 sub-projects (because of some specific dependencies). So the way that the python 3 modules use the python 2 programs is by calling them explicitly using Popen (because we can't just import them).

I've tried using pipenv but it seems that I can't create an environment for python 2 and python 3.
I tried creating a python script that just creates wheels from all of the projects (using both of the versions) but it seems kind of hacky and wrong.

So the question is - What is the best way to package a project that uses multiple python versions?

Comment: If you're using packages that still require Python2, you should consider finding alternatives. At the very least, copy those entirely or run `2to3` on them

Comment: Like I said, I can't do that because they are based on specific python 2 dependencies that work only on python 2.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Hmm, alright. Well, if you are able to expose services over web interfaces, then you could package and deploy a Python2 web server (e.g. Flask) that acts as a proxy to be called by Python3 code. Otherwise, you cannot package them together and by using Popen, you're requiring both be installed on the same system

Comment: Yes I want all of them installed in the same machine without using flask :\

Comment: You can still use HTTP calls on the same machine. Or maybe there is an IPC/RPC Python library. My point is that there's binary incompatibilities, you'll need to define a common bridge of some sort

Comment: Dude there's no need for a bridge.. All that is needed is to package python 2 and python 3 packages together in the same environment (and to be installed in the same environment)

Comment: Well, it won't be done by virtualenv/conda or pip... You can use Pyinstaller to freeze the apps independently, but you still need *something* to make them talk to each other. `Popen` **is** a plain text bridge that you're required to manually parse. With the protocols I mentioned, you have more structure over the results

Comment: The bridging is not a problem :\ Even with the protocols, the packaging problem would still exist

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not only packaging. You're stuck using the interpreter tools for each Python version independently, and therefore you'll be shuffling around two binaries rather than one. I'm sure there are lots of vendors out there doing this already - Dropbox for example runs several Python based processes communicating with each other on a machine at a given time between the UI and the sync processes.

The second problem is sharing results between interpreters, that's one of the goals of the [`execnet` library](https://codespeak.net/execnet/example/hybridpython.html), but basically makes a shared memory channel outside of the local process space, and defines a common serialization protocol between each process. `Popen` is not very reliable if the commands you're calling don't have deterministic results and you want to further manipulate the results after it returns.

This IPC approach can be extended over a network to RPC or HTTP if you wanted to host your applications on external servers or using Docker, for example, which is one of the reasons microservices are popular - you can independently deploy and scale different "bounded contexts"